# Python Requests Open Multiple Instances

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there a way to open multiple browsers in python with requests? I am getting data off a site that has 6,000,000 pages. If I had the ability to open 10 at a time it would no doubt run faster. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Multiprocessing or async calls.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html), an asynchronous version of the `requests` module. You can get the loop it speaks of with

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

Answer (score 2):

As @colidyre mentioned, you can use Multiprocessing or Asynchronous calls. You can also use a library such as [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) which will be using multiprocessing or asynchronous threads behind the scenes.